# QML Detect discarded state of HTML container

Tags: qt, qml, containers, state

I'm using QML with a webengineview container and that webengineview container is killed sometimes (when CPU is high).

My question is, how can I detect with QML the [app entered in discarded state](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#LifecycleState-prop) for reloading the container?

Comment: webview or webengineview?

Comment: Can't you just connect to the onLifecycleStateChanged signal and check for the discarded state?

Comment: @eyllanesc webengineview

Comment: @JarMan Yes, that it was I need, but I didn't find an example in QML. Do you have one? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be like this:

```
WebEngineView {
    onLifecycleStateChanged: {
        if (lifecycleState === LifecycleState.Discarded) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you need to listen for the state from a different object, you can use a Connections object:

```
Connections {
    target: myWebEngineView
    onLifecycleStateChanged: {
        if (lifecycleState === LifecycleState.Discarded) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Or, you could simply bind a property directly to the state and use it however you want to:

```
property bool isDiscarded: myWebEngineView.lifecycleState === LifecycleState.Discarded
```